# Angular unable to load view after url change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn angularjs.I wan't to share data between two controllers of two different pages. After googling came to know about services and created one service. From one page I am able to call my rest service and able to get data. After I am trying to redirect to different page. URL is changing but page is not loaded. Stuck here. Please find the code below. Anybody can help me where I am doing wrong?

data.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="/">
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js">  </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular-resource.min.js"></script>


  <script src="app.js"></script>
 <script src="usercontroller.js"></script>
  <script src="userservice.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="UserController" >
<form>
    <input type="text" name="Name" ng-model="user.userName"> Name <br/>
    <input type="text" name="password"  ng-model="user.password"> Password    <br/>
      <button type="submit" ng-click="getUser(user)" >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

data2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="/">
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
 <script src="usercontroller.js"></script>
  <script src="userservice.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="UserController2" >
<form>
    <input type="text" name="Name" ng-model="user.userName"> Name <br/>
    <input type="text" name="password"  ng-model="user.password"> Password  <br/>
      <button type="submit" ng-click="shareUser()" >Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

```
app.js


var App = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute','ngResource']);


App.config(['$routeProvider',
   function (
    $routeProvider
) {
      $routeProvider.
          when('/home', {
              templateUrl: 'data.html',
            controller: 'UserController'
          }).
          when('/welcome', {
             templateUrl: '/data2.html',
            controller: 'UserController2'
          }).
          otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/home'
          });
}]);

    usercontroller.js


 App.controller('UserController', ['$scope', 'UserService', '$window',       function($scope, UserService,$window,$location) {
   alert("inside user controller");
  var self = this;
  $scope.user={};
  $scope.user.userName="murali";
  $scope.user.password="murali123";

  $scope.getUser = function(user){
   alert("inside function");
         UserService.getUser(user).then(function(data){
      alert("data::"+JSON.stringify(data.userName));
     $window.location.href ='/welcome';
 });
      };

}]);

    App.controller('UserController2', ['$scope', 'UserService',  function($scope, UserService) {
   alert("inside user controller");

  $scope.user={};


 $scope.findUser = function(){
   alert("inside function");
        $scope.user = UserService.findUser();
        alert("userName::"+$scope.user.userName);

      };

 }]);

userservice.js

  App.factory('UserService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
  var user = {};
  return {

     getUser : function(user){
                return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/user/login',  angular.toJson(user))
                        .then(
                                function(response){
                                    alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                                    user=response.data;
                                    return response.data;
                                }, 
                                function(errResponse){
                                    console.error('Error while getting  response');
                                    return $q.reject(errResponse);
                                }
                        );
        },


        shareUser : function(){
            return user;
        }


         };
 }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you redirect the entire page is reloaded and the service is created from 0, no data is saved, unless you store it in `cookie` or `local/session storage`. But I see you are using `angular-route`, so, you can still get it done.

First, when using `angular-route`, the views does not need to be a full html doc and instead just a piece of it. Example:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="usercontroller.js"></script>
    <script src="userservice.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <ng-view></ng-view> <!-- Required by angular-route -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, note the `<ng-view></ng-view>` element, it is required by `angular-route` and is where the views will be loaded.

**data.html**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="Name" ng-model="user.userName"> Name <br/>
    <input type="text" name="password"  ng-model="user.password"> Password    <br/>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="getUser(user)" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

**data2.html**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="Name" ng-model="user.userName"> Name <br/>
    <input type="text" name="password"  ng-model="user.password"> Password  <br/>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="findUser()" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Note that in `data2.html` I changed `ng-click="shareUser()"` to `ng-click="findUser()"` as `UserController2` does not have a `shareUser` function.

Now, in `UserController` instead of using `window.location.href ='/welcome';` use `$location.path('/welcome');`, this is what you need to use to navigate without reloading the entire page, `angular-route` will do the magic. You will need to add the `$location` service as a dependency.

In `UserController2`, change `UserService.findUser();` to `UserService.shareUser();` because `UserService` does not have a `findUser` function, and I think `shareUser` is what you are trying to use.

Also, take a look again to the `$routeProvider` configuration, `'/data2.html'` might be pointing to the wrong location.

And you are ready, reload the page and happy coding.